# How to match a box collider to a mesh with code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem:
[image: problem]

This is a generated triangle. I want to add more vertices later (4,5,6...). For the moment I want to add an collider2d for this meshes. Later I have pentagons and hexagons, this is the reason why I think that I need a BoxCollider2D.

After this:

```
        BoxCollider2D boxCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
```

I get the above result. When I add this:

```
        MeshRenderer renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    boxCollider.offset = renderer.bounds.center;
    boxCollider.size = renderer.bounds.size;
```

All my triangles are matched together:

[image: matched]

And I get this error message in the added Box Collider2D:

[image: error]

I simply want to match the collider (green) to the mesh.

Comment: did you try a `MeshCollider` instead?

Comment: This triangles/pentagons etc.. arent static. I need a Rigidbody for this.

Comment: than enable `Convex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your mesh is generated procedurally, your bounds might be incorrect. To fix this call

```
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
```